# how to use filter or where clause in ng-for using angular2

Tags: angular

[image]

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
   <tr *ngFor="let item of faculytLectureMaster "> 
    <td>{{item.lectstart}}</td>
    <td>{{item.lectend}}</td>
    <td>{{item.facultyname}}</td>
    <td>{{item.subjectname}}</td>
    <td>{{item.subjectcode}}</td>
    <td>{{item.section}}</td>
    <td>{{item.attendtotal}}</td>
    <td>{{item.present}}</td>
    <td>{{item.absent}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I want to use filter for `*ngFor` like   `subjectname!='Break'` and `facultyname!='NA'`

How to write filter for `*ngFor` for angular2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same by using `ngIf` inside `ngFor`

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="faculytLectureMaster" let-i="index">
    <tr *ngIf="item.subjectname != 'Break' && item.facultyname != 'NA'"> 
      <td>{{item.lectstart}}</td>
      <td>{{item.lectend}}</td>
      <td>{{item.facultyname}}</td>
      <td>{{item.subjectname}}</td>
      <td>{{item.subjectcode}}</td>
      <td>{{item.section}}</td>
      <td>{{item.attendtotal}}</td>
      <td>{{item.present}}</td>
      <td>{{item.absent}}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</table>
```

Comment: this work *ngIf="item.subjectname != 'Break' && item.facultyname != 'NA'"